# .Where method not defined on generic typed list?

Tags: vb.net, generics

When I try to use the `.Where()` method on a list, this does method does not seem to be defined if the list is of a generic type:

In my program, I have a class called `Warning`, and in another class, a list of warnings, defined as:

```
Dim warningList As List(Of Warning)
```

When I try to manipulate this list as:

```
Dim item = warningList.Where(Function(x) x.GetName() = "Foo").FirstOrDefault()
```

This works completely fine, but when I try it like this:

```
Dim itemList
if(type = "Warning") Then 'Please note that this condition is true...
    itemList = warningList
End If

Dim item = itemList.Where(Function(x) x.GetName() = "Foo").FirstOrDefault()
```

I get an exception, stating that method `.Where()` is not defined for class `Warning`

Can anybody tell me why this is?
Thank you!

Comment: That's not the real code. If `warningList` is really a `List(Of Warning)` you should be able to use `Enumerable.Where`(if LINQ is imported). The fact that you assign this instance to another variable (on declaration) doesn't change anything because that variable's type is also a `List(Of Warning)`. So `itemList.Where` should work too. `Warning` has nothing to do with it because the type which is extended by `Where` is `IEnumerable(Of T)`, `T` can be any type(even `Object`). Since `List(Of T)` implements `IEnumerable(Of T)` you can use `Enumerable.Where` on any list (or array).

Comment: You're right, I just created a test project with just this code, and that seems to work, so I will search what my real problem is... Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Adapted my question now, it seems it's the `If` statement that makes the difference? Now I have the same behaviour in my test project...

Comment: You get an exception because an unassigned itemList is not the same as an empty list. Before you assign to it, it's `Nothing`. You can fix this by changing to `Dim itemList = New List(Of Warning)` - this creates an empty list.

Comment: @romkyns: The condition is true, so `itemList` is not `Nothing` (I can see that in the debugger). Editted question to make this more clear. The purpose of this is that sometimes (based on `type`) it needs to be a list of other objects.

Comment: Right, got it. I think itemList is of type Object. I would recommend you turn on Strict mode (`Option Strict On`) to make this error happen at compile time rather than when you run the code. The fix is `Dim itemList As List(Of Warning)`, I reckon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've edited your question it's clear.

You *declare* `itemList` without a type, so it's `Object` implicitly(in VB.NET with option strict set to `Off` which i strongly recommend against).

Now that you have declared a variable of type Object you can asssign any type to it. But you would have to cast it back to its real type `List(Of Warning)` to be able to use list or LINQ methods(which extend `IEnumerable(Of T)`.

But instead declare it with the correct type:

```
Dim itemList As List(Of Warning)
if(type = "Warning") Then
    itemList = warningList
End If

Dim item = itemList.Where(Function(x) x.GetName() = "Foo").FirstOrDefault()
```

Including to comment to explain why `Warning` is not related to this problem:

> That's not the real code. If `warningList` is really a `List(Of Warning)`
>   you should be able to use `Enumerable.Where`(if LINQ is
>   imported). The fact that you assign this instance to another variable
>   (on declaration) doesn't change anything because that variable's type
>   is also a `List(Of Warning)`. So `itemList.Where` should work too. `Warning`
>   has nothing to do with it because the type which is extended by `Where`
>   is `IEnumerable(Of T)`, `T` can be any type(even `Object`). Since `List(Of T)`
>   implements `IEnumerable(Of T)` you can use `Enumerable.Where` on any list
>   (or array).

---

If you actually have multiple types and `Warning` is just one of it, you should implement a common interface. Here's an example:

```
Public Enum NotificationType
    Warning
    Info
    [Error]
End Enum

Public Interface INamedNotification
    ReadOnly Property Type As NotificationType
    Property Name As string
End Interface

Public Class Warning
    Implements INamedNotification
    Public Sub New( name As String )
        Me.Name = name
    End Sub
    Public Property Name As String Implements INamedNotification.Name
    Public ReadOnly Property Type As NotificationType Implements INamedNotification.Type
        Get
            Return NotificationType.Warning
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Now you can declare a `List(Of INamedNotification)` and fill it with whatever implements this interface, like the `Warning` class:

```
Dim notificationList As List(Of INamedNotification)
if type = "Warning" Then 
    itemList = warningList
Else If type = "Info"
    itemList = infoList  
End If

Dim item = notificationList.Where(Function(x) x.Name = "Foo").FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius! I always assumed that it would do the cast to `List(Of Warning)` implicitly at runtime when a value was assigned to the empty variable. I was wrong. Thank you!

Comment: @DrDonut: you should really consider to change `Option Strict to ON`. You get a lot of compiler errors but they will actually help you to understand .NET and the type-system. Otherwise you are always vulnerable to such issues. Note that i've edited my answer to show you a way if you have multiple lists of different but related types.

Comment: Thank you! Will do.